How to remove lock cylinder without key?
I need to rekey a storm door as the previous owner lost the key. I am rookie but was able to open the face plates to reveal the lock cylinder. However, I am unable to open the lock cylinder so that I could take it to locksmith for rekeying.

What type of lock is this - Schlage, weissner etc?
Is there a hairpin that I need to rotate or a "knob" that needs to be pushed from 9 o'clock position to 12?

I spent countless hours on the internet/youtube. I tried to find something that could be pushed using a long needle but no luck, tried messing with the key hole with a wire but no luck. Tried to peep into the internals through the screw holes but cannot figure out what I need to do to remove the lock cylinder. So close yet so far!
Any pointers?



Remove hinges, take to locksmith. Or call a locksmith who will come to you (often costs more - though in some cases it may not, if the locksmith is one that only operates mobile and does not have the expense of maintaining a storefront you can come to. Shop around.)

thanks @Ecnerwal i am worried about removing hinges as I am not comfortable. i will look into calling a locksmith - i am hesitant because how much they charge but i will look into it.

Make sure you know the price of a whole new storm door, as that's the other option here. Not much point paying twice as much for a locksmith as replacement would cost you.

These cylinders are pretty easy to snap or drill. Here's an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQShSakZjvA&t=30s

thanks @bobflux. i have the tool but is there a scope for damaging the cylinder if I snap using that tool?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQyYLxgbhsE

Yes the cylinder will be broken if you snap it, that's the point. Then you extract it and replace with another cylinder for which you have the key. There is a risk of damaging the part of the lock that holds the cylinder, but that is cheaper to replace than the door.

Look up installation instructions for storm door handlesets, e.g. Andersen 3000.  That darker-colored screw on the trim plate just to the right of your red arrow tip appears to be what secures the lock cylinder in place—have you removed that screw?

@Huesmann yes, I removed it but no luck. lock cylinder just juggles but does not come out. I am suspecting I need to somehow rotate the cam that is in locked position.
